# Young engineer wanting to work in the industry: is PhD worth it?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, industrial-engineering

I'll soon get my engineering diploma (~MSc, from a "renowned-but-not-in-the-top-3" so-called french *grande école*). The degree itself is not specialized, but I mainly studied mechanical and industrial engineering.
I aim to work in the industry – or, in other words, I don't want to make an academic career... even if I am still not sure, what position I will look for (R&D, project management, or maybe even entrepreneurship). I'd be ok to work for some years (4-12 years) abroad (Europe of further), but I think that I'd like to come back to France at some point.

So I'm now wondering if doing a PhD in France (i.e. during 3 years) would be worth it, regarding my estimated career plan.
Question: What would then be the **pros and cons  I should consider** before choosing to do (or not) a PhD?

---

<sub>This question have been asked on Academia.SE. According to comments/advices there, I do ask it again here.
 I wanted to add these tags, but I don't have enough rep on this site to do it: `job`, `career`, `phd`.</sub>

Comment: Welcome to Engineering! This looks like an [academic guidance question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/261/1832). Such questions often involve personal choice and can probably be better answered by an adviser or counselor. We do not believe this site's format is well-suited to such questions, which are therefore considered off-topic.

Comment: Yes! The worth of the papers is, unfortunately, inflating. An MSc is far not enough for anything.

Comment: @Wasabi I do understand such question might be off-topic regarding this site guidelines. I tried to make it not too *opinion-based* by asking pros and cons (i.e. facts), rather than advices. These pros/cons could be given by experienced engineers around there.

Comment: @peterh what do you mean by "Far not enough for anything". Is that a serious or facetious statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A PhD is specifically geared towards academic research and so if you are working in a more 'pure' field like maths or physics it is certainly a good thing. However engineering is not by any means a pure academic field and so there is a reasonable argument that industrial experience is at least as valuable.

Equally PhD research tends to be quiet niche and you may be limited in what you can research by the facilities of your chosen institution and the interests of the available academic supervisors.

If you are unsure it may not be bad advice to look at working industry for a year or so and then evaluating your options.

One thing about engineering is that it is always very useful to have some experience of getting your hands dirty at actually making things. Ultimately engineering is about pragmatic problem solving, something which academic qualifications are not necessarily all that great at teaching.

There is also a potential problem that if you have a PhD you end up overqualified for junior positions but don't have the specific knowledge and experience required for more senior ones, especially if you don't have a very strong interest in a particular field.

There is also an argument that a year spent working in a foundry, fabrication or machine shop will give you an insight into the real world practicalities of engineering which you will not get elsewhere.

Comment: Engineering departments in universities often have links to industry, and PhD projects may be related to a real-world problem and partially funded by the company. That is a good arrangement, since the student and the company get to know each other over a period of several years, and it can lead to a job offer at the end of the PhD - though that is not guaranteed!

Comment: @alephzero But I guess the question is whether it's worth 4+ years of your life on the hopes you'll be able to make better connections with the industry. Isn't it still roughly a dichotomous choice between whether you want to work in academia vs industry? Weighing the benefits and costs of your idea to get a PhD to make connections seems to have way too much an opportunity y cost.